# Obscure proof that $+$ and $\times$ are continuous?

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, continuity, proof-writing, alternative-proof

> I am looking for proof of  $+$ and $\times$ are continuous operations
>   without using the standard definition of continuity
>   (1. $\epsilon-\delta$, or 2. preimage of *open* sets or 3. sequential continuity) Any other proof would be considered valid for this purpose

Define: Addition and multiplication as mappings

$+: \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, (a,b) \mapsto a+b$

$\times: \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, (a,b) \mapsto a \times b$

> Using [obscure definition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1358951/example-of-strict-inclusion-in-continuity-condition-f-overlinea-subseteq-o) of continuity:
>
> $f$ is continuous if $\forall A \subset \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}, f(\overline A) \subseteq \overline {f(A)}$

We know that singletons are closed in $\mathbb{R}$, closed sets are closed under cartesian product, so $A = \{a\} \times \{b\} \subset \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ is closed

$f(\{a\} \times \{b\}) = f(\overline{\{a\} \times \{b\}}) = \overline{f(\{a\} \times \{b\})}$

The latter equality because $f(\{a\} \times \{b\})$ is a singleton, so $f$ is continuous

**Can someone please check on the validity?** **And perhaps offer an alternative proof, thanks**

Comment: Are you asking whether your proof works (which it doesn't, because it only handles the case where $A$ consists of $1$ point - and applies to *all* functions $f$, regardless of continuity), or for other proofs of continuity?

Comment: That definition of continuity (which is hardly obscure) involves an arbitrary set $A$, not just singletons.

Comment: Why not just use sequential continuity and the rules for limits of sequences: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_sequence

Comment: As pointed out above you have not met the requirements of the "obscure definition" of continuity. For separable metric spaces, that definition is just sequential continuity in an elaborate disguise. You need to say more about your motivation for asking the question.

Comment: The whole point is to prove this without the usual definitions..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an easy way to tell that *something* must be wrong with your proof: what sort of assumptions on $f$ does it use? Your proof doesn't assume *anything* about $f$, so - if it were valid - would prove that *every* function is continuous.

The flaw, as the comments have pointed out, is that you need to show $$f(\overline{A})\subseteq\overline{f(A)}$$ for **every** $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$, not just those of the form $\{a\}\times\{b\}$. Here's an example which might make this easier to visualize (on $\mathbb{R}$, instead of $\mathbb{R}^2$, for simplicity):

- Let $f(x)$ be the characteristic function of $\mathbb{Q}$: $1$ if $x$ is rational, $0$ if $x$ is not rational. (This is called the *Dirichlet function*.)
- Take $A=\mathbb{Q}$. What is $\overline{A}$? What is $f(\overline{A})$?
- On the other hand, what is $f(A)$? What is $\overline{f(A)}$?

In terms of using this definition to prove things, I think it's generally faster to *first* prove that this is equivalent to the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition, and then use that one; in most cases that makes things a little more concrete and easy to figure out (at least early on). Of course, Your Mileage May Vary.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't pose this question, someone posed this question to me and claimed that a short proof can be found not via the standard definitions but through their consequences and equivalent definitions..