# Why would the projection function open and not closed?

Tags: general-topology, functions

Given $p: \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, (x,y) \mapsto x$

Why is $p$ open but not closed?

Shouldn't it be the case $p$ is closed not open because it sends a singleton to singleton, and all singletons in Euclidean spaces are closed?

Comment: There are many closed sets that are not singletons.

Comment: You seem to have made the same error of trying to prove a statement of the form "For all closed $A$, ..." by considering only singletons in [this other question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1812810/obscure-proof-that-and-times-are-continuous#comment3704648_1812810) of yours. It's perhaps worth watching out for the error of treating on a specific instance of "for all" when it doesn't represent the general case.

Comment: Please don’t take it amiss when I say that we should never ask why something isn’t true. What we need in all cases is a proof when it is true.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The set $F=\{(\frac{1}{n},n):n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ because it has no limit points, but its projection onto the $x$ coordinate is the set $\{\frac{1}{n}:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$, which is not closed because it doesn't contain the limit point $0$. Therefore the projection is not a closed map.

Comment: Would have never thought of that example

Comment: @Lookbehindyou Would you have thought of the example $\{(x,y):xy=1\}$? It's a closed set (because it's a level set of the continuous function $f(x,y)=xy$) but its projection $\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$ is not closed.

Answer (score 0):

You could also think about the set $S=\{ (t, \tan(t)): -\pi/2<t<\pi/2\}. $

This set is closed in $\mathbb{R}^2$, but its projection over the $x$-axis is not closed in $\mathbb{R}$.